# How can I get sound from a Boxes VM?

Tags: audio, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, gnome-boxes

I am running an Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS VM on a PureOS 8.0 host, running GNOME Boxes 3.30.3 and a QEMU session broker. The VM has spice-vdagent 0.17.0 installed. I cannot get audio in the VM to play.

I have the volume up on the VM and host. The VM sound device is called "Dummy Sound". If I "Test Speakers" with the Sound control panel, or play a YouTube video, there is no sound.

I found a [2016 blog post about running Windows 10 on Boxes](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-win10-in-gnome-boxes.html) that suggests that audio is a Boxes feature:

> Self-configuring audio output for Windows 10 and 8 in GNOME Boxes is pending [a bug]. To get audio working you can use one of these two options:
>
> Option 1: [Edit QEMU XML file. I tried this, there is no `<sound>` tag in my XML file.]
>
> Option 2: [Use USB sound card. I don't have a USB sound card.]

How can I play sound in the VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your QEMU.xml to use the Intel HD audio adapter to work around [bug #761031](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761031).

Open Boxes, perform a full shut down of the virtual machine, and note the auto-assigned name given to the virtual machine. Open up the Terminal and type **EDITOR=gedit virsh edit** *YOURBOXNAME*.

If you’ve modified the name after installing, you can find the file in ~/.config/libvirt/qemu/, but don’t edit it directly — rather use the name with the previous command. Add the lines below, save and close the file.

> ```
> <sound model='ich6'>
>   <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
> </sound>
> ```

Found this in the [dead fedoraproject archives](https://askbot.fedoraproject.org/en/question/130768/no-sound-in-gnome-boxes/).

If slot `0x04` is already used, try `0x06`.

If you'd prefer not to edit the XML directly, you can:

- Install Virtual Machine Manager (`virt-manager`)
- Add a new "QEMU/KVM user session" connection to [show your Boxes in the VM manager interface](https://blog.agchapman.com/configuring-gnome-boxes-vms-using-virt-manager/)
- Show the virtual hardware details, select "Add Hardware" and add an `HDA (ICH6)` Sound device (this will select the slot for you)
- Start the machine in Boxes as normal

Comment: When I run the command EDITOR=gedit virsh edit YOURBOXNAME (replacing YOURBOXNAME with xml file name boxes-unknown) I get the error 
error: failed to get domain 'boxes-unknown'
error: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'boxes-unknown'